# Sign in problems to access garage in GT5

Tags: gran-turismo-5

We have an old user login that my son has forgotten the password to, and the e-mail address linked to this user, so we can't sign in.

Is there any way to access the contents of garage/saved data on GT5 for this login?

Answer (score 2):

Saves on the PS3 are generally inextricably linked to a PSN ID, in order to prevent cheating. So even if you copied the save game files to another account or another PS3 you would not be able to access them without logging in to the associated PSN account.

I would try contacting Sony's customer support, they may be able to help you recover the account details.